# Usage of Firefox Add-ons in C# GeckoFX control

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am writing a browser application using C# Language and GeckoFX Browser library.

Now, I want to add the Mozilla Firefox Add-on to my application.

To be precise, I want my application to block undesirable advertisement using [AdBlock Plus add-on for Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/vi/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/).

Is it possible to use a Firefox add-on in my GeckoFX control?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question so that it becomes a little bit more clear and answerable. Also, I have removed a "Thanks" comment because it is unnecessary. If you have any questions, please, do not hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly because Firefox extensions are largely based around the interface and working of Firefox's UI, not just the Gecko interface, I don't think it would be possible at all currently to install extensions or .XPI files.

So in order to do this without using an extension, you may have to code an adblocker yourself which I've been trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718536/how-to-build-an-adblocker-for-geckofx-browser-in-winform).

Otherwise, good luck! I've been having similar issues and am looking towards writing my own solution.